# Realizability in mathematics

Tags: terminology, education

What does it mean in mathematics when someone says "it is realizable"? If someone could give me a general and intuitive explanation I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one lets $X$ be an object with a list of properties $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$, say, then it may not be apparent that an $X$ exists which satisfies these properties.  If there is such an $X$, we say $X$ is realizable, otherwise $X$ is not realizable.

A baseball home plate is not realizable ([link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomePlate.html)), since the required lengths and angles cannot be simultaneously achieved (it requires the existence of a right angled triangle with side lengths $12$, $12$ and $17$).

[image: Baseball home plate]